# jQuery .animate and negative margin-top in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8, jquery-animate

I'm having a problem with an animation in Internet Explorer 8. The code I'm using works in all good browsers, and even works as expected in Internet Explorer 7.

The basic layout is 2 divs floated on top of each other within a container div.

Just before the animation, I add a 3rd div on top of the other 2, with a height of 0 and a margin-top of -10 (the container div has a height matching the 2 within it, the new one should look like it's growing from the top of this).

I then use a .animate on the new div, and animate a height of x and a margin-top of -y (where -y is 10 more than x).

In every other browser the new div grows and the negative margin keeps it on top of the divs below.

But in Internet Explorer 8, the divs below jump on top of the new one!

This seems to be a margin issue because when I remove the margin from the animation, it no longer grows up, but the content does push down like you'd expect. Also, if I reset the margins on the sibling divs at the end of the animation, they magically go back into place (in fact experimenting with the IE developer tools I found changing just about any property on the siblings put them back into place).

Here is the animation code:

```
        var height_to_set = $('#splash').height() - 95;
        $('#splash').children('.tag').prepend('<div class="tag_explain"> </div>').children('.tag_explain').css( 'background-color' , bgc ).animate(
        {
            height:height_to_set,
            'margin-top':'-'+(height_to_set+10)+'px'
        } , 300 );
```

Does anyone have any suggestions as to what may be the issue here?